# AutoCompleteTextView exibir itens que possuem acento quando digitado sem acento

Tags: android, autocompletar, edittext, textview

Possuo um `AutoCompleteTextView`, definido como seu adapter tenho uma lista que recebe o nome de cidades como, por exemplo, São Paulo, porém se o informo no campo o valor Sao Paulo, sem o acento, ele não exibe nenhum item, isso por que provavelmente o `AutoCompleteTextView` não identifica o caractere `a == ã`.

Como posso fazer para que o valor com acento seja exibido quando o valor sem acento for digitado?

Código que criei separadamente para testes:

```
ArrayList<String>cidades = new ArrayList<>();

   cidades.add("São Paulo");
   cidades.add("São Luiz");

autoComplete = (AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);

ArrayAdapter<String> lista = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,cidades);

autoComplete.setAdapter(lista);
```

P.S.: Posso adicionar os itens sem acento na lista facilmente.

Comment: Vejo duas alternativas, as duas tem seus pontos a se pensar. É fato que a comparação tem que ser feita ignorando acentos. Mas isso não implica que precisa guardar o valor da lista sem acentos. A primeira alternativa é remover os acentos ao fazer a comparação. A outra é armazenar os valores com e sem acento, e ao comparar, usar o sem acento. Dependendo da quantidade de dados, vale a pena gastar um pouco mais de memória ou gastar um pouco mais de cpu. Ah e pra remover acentos, essa resposta vai ajudar bastante: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523631/remove-accents-from-string

Comment: Bem a lista com os valores com e sem acentos eu já possuo, ela é preenchida com informações do meu banco de dados que já possui uma coluna normalizada com o nome sem acento, mas como faço para implementar a comparação sem os acentos, com qual classe ou método e que o valor exibido no autocompletetextview seja o com o acento?

Comment: Hmm, massa, como está o seu `Adapter`? Acho que provavelmente vai precisar criar um `Adapter` customizado para isso.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o trecho do código.